# MarkLogic template debugging: how to increase productivity?

Tags: marklogic

I'm trying to debug a MarkLogic pipeline and every time I change one of the xquery files that's used by the pipeline I have to run a homemade script we have that reloads ALL the system modules.  I'm guessing this is a technique that was developed when the project only had a few modules, but now it takes several minutes for this processs.  What I need is either 1) a faster technique to reload just the one module I changed, e.g. a code snippet I could run in CQ or 2) some entirely different approach.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Normally you could run your code from file-system directly, but that won't work with pipelines.

Second easiest thing is to just use a webdav app server, and a webdav capable editor (like oXygen). All you need to do is to create a new app server of the webdav type, connect that to the modules database you want to access, make sure you have an account to login with, and you are ready.

Other approaches are using a smarter system to upload only changed files. Ant is usually quite good at detecting changes. And there are MarkLogic ant tasks available on github ( https://github.com/garyvidal/marklogic-ant-tasks ). Not sure though that really works better though, you would have to try. You might have to think your build script through well. Last time I used it, it works reasonably well though, certainly not minutes, even though it loaded a few hundred files if I am not mistaken.

There may be a different reason though why the approach you use is so slow. If you are able to disclose it, you could ask for concrete optimization tips.

Comment: How does connecting through WebDAV solve the problem of ML having to dump its cache (or whatever it does, compile?) of the module?  Thanks!

Comment: To my knowledge modules are compiled and cached at first access (initial or after update). It should not slow down the updating AFAIK. That behavior is the same for all ways you use to update the module, so no different for WEBDAV uploads to the modules database..

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused about the need to reload "ALL the system modules". Maybe you should try the latest server release, or check with support?

But assuming you simply want to reload your own code, you could use RecordLoader: https://github.com/marklogic/recordloader

If you would rather use cq, you could start with http://developer.marklogic.com/pubs/4.2/apidocs/AdminBuiltins.html#xdmp:filesystem-directory - this might get you started. You'll probably need to add document permissions to the doc-insert call, and you may need to do more string manipulation to build the URI.

```
declare namespace dir="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/directory";

if (xdmp:database('Modules') eq xdmp:database()) then ()
else error(
  (), 'INSTALL-NOTMODULES', text {
    xdmp:database-name(xdmp:database()), 'is not the Modules database' })
,
for $i in xdmp:filesystem-directory('/path/to/files')/dir:entry
  [dir:type eq 'file']
  [ends-with(dir:filename, '.xqy')]
let $uri := $i/filename/string()
return xdmp:document-insert($uri, xdmp:document-get($i/dir:pathname))
```

Comment: Sorry my post wasn't clear: bottom line is I just need a targetted way to reload the one or two xqy files i'm working in.  Does ML simply require that the file be re-inserted into the db from the filesystem?  I'll look at RecordLoader.  I continue to be frustrated by what feels like an extremely archaic development environment with little tooling...I digress.  I use Oxygen instead of CQ so that at least I can get syntax color highlighting.  Thanks again.

Comment: I guess the real question in my mind is why I can modify some xqy files and immediately see the results; however apparently for any xqy file touched by a pipeline, this doesn't work -- and I'm not clear on what exactly has to be done to remedy that.

Comment: CPF pipelines are implemented by triggers, and those CPF triggers evaluate with their module root set to the Modules database. So the normal way to install code used by a trigger is to copy it into the Modules database. An application server, on the other hand, can use a filesystem location as its root. One alternative is to use /opt/MarkLogic/Modules (on linux - other environments differ). Modules in that filesystem location are universally available.

Answer (score 1):

Using a technique in Marklogic Ant Tasks and an XCC connection(any doesnt have to point to your database): 
https://github.com/garyvidal/marklogic-ant-tasks

You can use the  Here is something you can use in your template:

```
<!--Define ml namespace in project root element-->
<project name="ML Build Task" xmlns:ml="http://www.marklogic.com/ant">
>
<!--Set you the classpath to where your mlant.jar file is located.
    Include any other dependent jar files required to execute tasks
    noted in Dependencies section.
-->
<path id="mlant-classpath">
    <fileset dir="${lib-dir}">
          <include name="xcc.jar" />
          <include name="mlant.jar" />
          <include name="corb.jar"/>
          <include name="saxon9he.jar"/>
          <include name="xqdoc-ml.jar"/>
          <include name="antlr-2.7.5.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>
<!--
   Setup the type definition and assign classpathref to mlant-classpath
-->
<typedef 
   uri="http://www.marklogic.com/ant" 
   resource="com/marklogic/ant/antlib.xml"
   classpathref="mlant-classpath"
/>
<!--Optional: Set the property for xccstring used to connect to MarkLogic database-->
<property name="xccstring" value="xcc://test:test@localhost:9090/Docs">

<!--Create a target element and use the tasks-->
<target name="load-modified">
     <ml:load xccurl="${xccstring}">
          <ml:docset destdir="/app-code/">
              <ml:permissionset>
                  <ml:permission role="nobody" permission="execute" />
                  <ml:permission role="nobody" permission="insert" />
                  <ml:permission role="nobody" permission="read" />
                  <ml:permission role="nobody" permission="update" />
              </ml:permissionset>
              <ml:collectionset>
                  <ml:collection name="collection1" />
                  <ml:collection name="collection2" />
              </ml:collectionset>
              <fileset dir="../src" includes="**/*" >
                 <modified/>
              </fileset>                  
          </ml:docset>
      </ml:load>
</target>

<!--Have Fun-->
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to make your Modules upload go faster: clear your Modules database, turn off "directory creation: automatic",and use something like RecordLoader with multiple threads configured.  If you don't set directory creation to automatic writes into the modules database will get into locking contention and effectively be single threaded.